# borderRadius is not true in PinCodeTextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I create an pin code text field like below, but when i try using `shape: PinCodeFieldShape.circle,` my console throw me

```
'package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart': Failed assertion: line 130 pos 12: 'shape != BoxShape.circle ||
          borderRadius == null': is not true.
```

have anybody any idea how to solve this problem?

my code:

```
  Widget _pinCode(){
    return PinCodeTextField(
      length: 4,
      // obsecureText: false,
      // animationType: AnimationType.fade,
      shape: PinCodeFieldShape.circle,
      // animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(),
      fieldHeight: 50,
      fieldWidth: 40,
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      onChanged: (value){
        print(value);
      },
    );
  }
```

second question:
how to set padding/margin between every pin code text field?

thanks for any ansewers :)

Comment: I don't understand the questions ...

Comment: all this code is from this package ```pin_code_fields: 2.5.1```, here is documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

Comment: I just created a sample app with your code and it works fine (without any change in your code), seems like the issue is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. I fixed it by the removing the `borderRadius` property. The `shape` property does not work well with `borderRadius`.

```
Widget _pinCode(){
    return PinCodeTextField(
         length: 4,
         // obsecureText: false,
         // animationType: AnimationType.fade,
         shape: PinCodeFieldShape.circle,
         // animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
         //borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(),
         fieldHeight: 50,
         fieldWidth: 40,
         activeColor: Colors.red,
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         onChanged: (value){
           print(value);
         },
    );   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using my package. The reason it doesn't work because circle shape already has it's own radius so you don't need to provide an extra border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to solve this is to use a conditional statement

```
borderRadius: isCircle == true ? null : BorderRadius.all(...)
```

so if it is a circle `borderRadius` will be set to `null`;

with this condition, the shape can be added, but make sure if it is circle, the `borderRadius` must be set to `null`